# unable to redirect the url after get data from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, redirect

I get the data through ajax then I validate it and redirect user as per condition. Like if user login successful then redirect to dashboard otherwise redirect to restrict page. I get the result data in network console(developers tool) but I am unable to redirect to specific page.
Here is my index.php page.

```
<div id="loginContainer">
   <form id="loginFrm" method="post">
      <h3>Members Login Area</h3>
      <img id="divider" src="images/divider.png">
      <input type="email" name="lemail" required placeholder="Enter a valid email address">
      <input name="lpassword" placeholder="Password" type="password" required>
      <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
      <input id="submit" type="hidden" name="submit">
      <p><a href="#">Forgot Password ?</a></p>
      <p id="bottom">Don't have account? <a href="#" id="signup">Sign up here</a></p>
   </form>
</div>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#loginFrm").submit(function () {
           var data = $("#loginFrm").serialize();
           insertRecords(data);
           return false;
       });
       function insertRecords(data) {
           $.ajax({
               url: 'loginProcess.php',
               data: data,
               type: 'POST',
               dataType: 'html',
               success: function (data) {
                   $("#result").html(data);
                   },
                   error: function () {
                       alert('Error : COde not work properly');
                   }
               });
           }
       });
</script>
```

This is my loginProcess.php page where i get the data from users input.

```
<?php
ob_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
print_r($_POST);// see all result in network console
require_once('inc/dbconnection.php');
require_once('inc/functions.php');
$emailErr = $password="";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

if (empty($_POST["lemail"])) {
    $emailErr = 'Please enter your email address.';
} else {
    $email = filterEmail($_POST["lemail"]);
    if ($email == FALSE) {
        $emailErr = 'Please enter a valid email address.';
    }
}
if (empty($_POST["lpassword"])) {
    $passwordErr = 'Please enter your password here.';
} else {
    $password = sha1($_POST['lpassword']);
}
}
// after pressing login, checking if the variables exist in the database
if (empty($emailErr) && empty($passwordErr)) {
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT password FROM users WHERE email=?");
    $query->execute(array($email));
    if ($query->fetchColumn() === $password) {
        // starts the session created if login info is correct
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        header("Location: dashboard.php",true, 302);
        exit;
    } else {
        header("Location: restrict.php",true, 302);
        exit;
    }
} else {
    header("Location: index.php?Email=$emailErr&Password=$passwordErr",true, 302);
    die;
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

**Note: i've checked after remove the (true, 302) in header function**

Answer (score 1):

You cannot redirect in `php` with `AJAX`. You need to redirect in `success` function of `AJAX` like below:

```
window.location.href = 'dashboard.php'
```

Comment: I use following but doesn't work for me.
echo ("<script>windowlocation.href = 'dashboard.php'</script>");

Comment: Try in response in success function like this  ===>  success: function (data) {
                  window.location.href = 'dashboard.php'
                },

Comment: if condition is not true then how to redirect to restrict page?

Comment: You need to add if else condition in you js only . Like if condtion is true then 'window.location.href = 'dashboard.php' OR if condition is false then 'window.location.href = 'restrict.php'

Comment: see whats my mistake... i always redirect in else part(restrict.php)

                        success: function (data) {
                        $("#result").html(data); 
                        if(data.success){
                        window.location = 'dashboard.php';
                    } else {
                        window.location = 'restrict.php';
                    }
                   },

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX request will fail if the page you're fetching the result from does not contain data in a format expected by the `ajax()` Javscript function (caused by a redirected result page).

Why not pass the URL from PHP to the Javascript function, **check if the URL to redirect to is set** then redirect accordingly instead?

```
window.location.replace('dashboard.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you should be redirecting from your PHP form processing script? I believe you should just generate the ERROR/NO ERROR response their and redirect the page from your form page by handling the AJAX response cases.